# Calculating the sum of a series (power series)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

By expanding $(r+1)^4 -r^4$ calculate $\sum r^3$

---

step 1 -  expand to get $1 + 4r + 6r^2 + 4r^3 $

step 2 - what should I do next to calculate the sum?

I don't really understand why we have been given $(r+1)^4 -r^4$. 
Why have we been given this? How does it help in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps, via what we would call telescoping. Note the following:
$$
(r+1)^4-r^4 = 4r^3 + 6r^2+4r+1
$$
Suppose we are asked to calculate $\sum_{r=1}^n r^3$. We would repeatedly substitute $r = 2,\ldots n$ in the above expression, and sum them up:
$$
2^4 - 1^4 = 4\cdot 1^3 + 6 \cdot 1^2 + 4\cdot r + 1
$$
$$
3^4 - 2^4 = 4\cdot 2^3 + 6 \cdot 2^2 + 4\cdot 2 + 1
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
(n+1)^4 - n^4 = 4\cdot n^3 + 6 \cdot n^2 + 4\cdot n + 1
$$
Add these all up, and see what is happening on the left side: terms are getting cancelled, and you will end up with $(n+1)^4 - 1^4$, and on the right side:
$$
4\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 + 6\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 + 4\sum_{i=1}^n i + n
$$
Now, we know that:$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} ; \sum_{i=1}^n i  = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
Substitute these:
$$
(n+1)^4-1 = 4\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 + 6\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right) + 4\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right) + n
$$
Simplify:
$$
(n+1)^4-1 = 4\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 + n(n+1)(2n+1) + 2n(n+1) + n
$$
Expand and collect like terms:
$$
4\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = n^4+2n^3+n^2 = n^2(n+1)^2
$$
Therefore, you will get:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2
$$
This is a technique, called telescoping, and the above can be extended by induction to larger powers.

Comment: In your 3rd sentence you said that terms are getting cancelled when you add them up. How are terms getting cancelled? They're all adding up because there is no minus.

Comment: I must be looking upside down: I meant the left side of the equalities, where the fourth powers are getting cancelled.

Comment: So when you do the sums, you said we know that the sum of i^2 =.... and i= .....  and you substitute and solve for the sum of i^3. How do you do this? Why aren't you also including in the sum of 4i^3?

Comment: @MATHSHELPNEEDED We do not know the value of $4\sum i^3$, but we know the value of everything else in the expression, so we can substitute them in, and the only unknown left behind will be $4\sum i_3$. Then we can simplify terms. It's better if I edit my answer.

Comment: @MATHSHELPNEEDED When processes are done inductively, that means that we already know the results for smaller cases. I could not have done this problem without knowing $\sum i^2$ and $\sum i$, because they are smaller inductive cases, and if I am solving by induction then I should be knowing their answers.

Comment: you are welcome.